# How can I call a C++ dll from VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dllexport

Well I have created a DLL using the [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/DLL/XDllPt1.aspx) from CP. For creating this DLL aslso, I have used VS2008. Now I am not sure how can I call this DLL from another C++ application created in VS2008. When I click on `Refrences>Add New Reference` this is asking for the project folder not for the DLL path.

In the Code Project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/DLL/XDllPt1.aspx) , there are few steps for Adding Preproccessor and setting up the link to the lib. I am not quite sure how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are  you talking about a managed DLL (.NET)? Only then you need to do the "Add New Reference" stuff.

If not: 
Together with your DLL a file with the extension ".lib" has been created (the import lib). 
Add it to your project of the calling application e.g. in the project settings:
"Configuration Properties" - "Linker" - "Input" - "Additional Dependencies".

In your source code add `#include "<name of the headerfile for your DLL>.h"`.